# Configuring Eureka Server and Microservices Communication: Error in Expanding Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-config-server

I'm working on a Spring 2.7.14 project, and I've successfully set up configuration between my microservices and the config server. Initially, I configured the Eureka Server using properties like:

```
server.port=8761
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=false
```

This setup worked fine. However, when I tried to establish a connection between the registration server (Eureka Server) and the config server, things started to break. My intention was to link the two by creating a `eurika-service.properties` file for configuration, then referencing it in `bootstrap.properties`. Unfortunately, after making these changes, the Eureka Server stopped functioning correctly.

In an attempt to resolve this issue, I introduced a dependency in the Eureka Server's `pom.xml` specifically for `bootstrap.properties`. Here's the added dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

My expectation was that this modification would enable the Eureka Server to retrieve its configuration from the config server as outlined in `spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888`. However, despite these adjustments, the Eureka Server and microservices still fail to communicate properly.

Comment: Can you be more specific on the "still fail to communicate properly"?